# Vertical/Column text select in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to select text vertically/in a column in PyCharm? You can do it in Visual Studio and Notepad++ by holding down alt+arrow keys.

The documentation describes how to do it with the mouse, but there's no mention of keyboard options.

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d306531e464

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (*Find Action* feature) and type *column*. The first result is *Column Selection Mode* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. After that, select text with keyboard (by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>)

Comment: Sorry, but that only enables column selection for mice. I'm trying to select with the keyboard.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle Not true. Afterwards you can select text with keyboard as usually (by holding `Shift` pressed).

Comment: Ohhh, I was trying to hold down Shift+Alt as I did with all the other programs. This mode switching is a bit awkward, but I guess I can live with it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning find action. It is command+shift+A  in Macs and I found the mac command for column select mode: command+shift+8.

Comment: The mode switching only needs to be done once, it shouldn't be too awkward then.

Comment: @Étienne in another answer provided more comfortable way, without change selection mode - press and release ctrl, then ctrl+arrows.

Answer (score 20):

In Mac, Hold **option + Shift** - and use mouse to select the text vertically

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted? The question is how to do it without the mouse.

Answer (score 19):

First press ctrl (press and release), then press ctrl+arrows to do the vertical selection.

Comment: @Gulzar I was using it on Windows.

Comment: Works on Linux. Very nice feature.

Comment: On MacOS, replace `ctrl` for `option`

Comment: ctrl + ctrl (keep ctrl) + up/down arrow on linux

Answer (score 13):

In the free version of Pycharm this is called Column Selection Mode and it's enabled pressing Shift + Command + 8

[image: Column Selection Mode]

Edit:  Noticed Ozgur Ozturk beat me to this in his comment and as he points out this combo is for Macs only

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Add Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` and add `Alt + Button1 Click` as a new action.

This will allow you to create rectangular selections across multiple rows and columns like you know it from Notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

If someone still searching (as I did): ALt + Shift + mouse works for me on windows